# Can't connection DB use ktor application

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I try start ktor application with postgresql database. For it i used  docker compose. My docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
   ktor-sample:
      build: ./
      command: ./ktor-sample
      ports:
         - "8080:8080"
      depends_on:
         - db
   db:
      restart: unless-stopped
      image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
      volumes:
         - ./test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
      - "5433:5433"
      environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: postgres
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
         POSTGRES_DB: AutoHistory
```

I every one receive error:

```
WARN  Exposed - Transaction attempt #2 failed: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. 
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting 
TCP/IP connections.. Statement(s): null
ktor-sample_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 
refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is 
accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

This database is created and can connection to it.

Answer (score 1):

As for me I do next I create an object for initializing of db

it can look like this

```
object DbFactory {
    fun init() {
        val pool = hikari()
        val db = Database.connect(pool)
        transaction(db) {
            SchemaUtils.create(Creators, Visitors, Places, Roles, UserRoles, Users)
        }
    }

    private fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {
        val hikariConfig = HikariConfig("db.properties")
        return HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)
    }

}
```

and in Application.kt, on the first place initialize your db

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        DbFactory.init()
...
```

the file which is describing your data should live in root and be called `db.properties` look something like

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/AutoHistory
dataSource.driverClass = org.postresql.Driver
dataSource.driver=postgresql
dataSource.database= AutoHistory
dataSource.user= postgres
dataSource.password=
```

I have no such rows in docker-compose.yml

```
   ktor-sample:
      build: ./
      command: ./ktor-sample
      ports:
         - "8080:8080"
      depends_on:
         - db
```

and do start my app manually but anyway I think it should help you

Comment: I added the initializeDatabase function of mines below the embeddedServer function. works flawlessly